# Why is there multiple style sheet containing css variables with same values?

Tags: css, sass

I used

```
:root {
  --colorBrand50: #eef2ff;
  --colorBrand100: #dce5fe;
... // around 750 color variables
}
```

in the scss file and link them to the scss variables and use scss variable (i.e.`$colorBrand50`) in my project.
However, after what I did, it generate plenty of `<style/>` in browser inspect with same set of css variables. Why does this happen?

[image]

[image]

Comment: a browser canIt read (intreped) SASS/LESS. SASS/LESS are precompilers that compile the scss file into normal CSS.

Comment: It depends on how you import your styles; if you import them in multiple places, they will load separately from every file.

Comment: @tacoshy I did try place `:root{}` in .css and import them into the .scss, I got the same result.

Comment: @SMAKSS I place them all in a single root file.